# Making \psfrag replacement without using --shell-escape option

Tags: pdftex, shell-escape, psfrag, auto-pst-pdf

I am trying to submit latex manuscript on ScholarOne. In the latex file, I have used \psfrag to make text replacement on `.eps` file. On my PC I can use `auto-pst-pdf` package and compile the `.tex` file using

```
pdflatex --shell-escape myDocument.tex
```

But when I submit it on ScholarOne, it can create a PDF file correctly except the \psfrag replacements. \psfrag replacements appear at random locations on the document. By looking at the log file, I can see that the shell-escape is not enabled, which might be causing the issue. It is possible to make \psfrag replacements without using `shell-escape` option.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Maybe you could use the following workaround: load the .eps in a `standalone` document, do your text replacements there and include the result as graphic in your main document

Comment: psfrag if usedwith pdftex just runs latex in teh background making a pdf to include, so you can include that file directly without using psfrag at all once it is made.

Comment: @samcarter that's basically what psfrag does anyway with pdftex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, that makes it even easier.

Comment: Can you show an example command to convert eps files to standalone graphic files including psfrag replacements? I found that `auto-pst-pdf` does generate a _filename_-pics.pdf file with proper `psfrag` replacements for all eps files. After generation of this file, I can compile without shell-escape by turning off  `auto-pst-pdf`. Even then, the ScholarOne submission system is not able to recognize _filename_-pics.pdf. It needs each graphics file separately. I figured, If I can make a separate standalone `.pdf` for each eps file, I can use them inside `\includegraphics` and avoid shell-escape.

Comment: Additionally, I also tried `\usepackage{epstopdf}` and it does generate separate pdf file for each eps file but without `psfrag` replacements. Is there a way to tell `epstopdf` to make `psfrag` replacements in the generated pdf files.